# GH/s is bigger than TH/s

Tags: blockchain, bitcoind, miner-configuration, hash, asic

How does BAIKAL X10 make more money than AntminerS9 although BAIKAL X10 Only 10 GH/s and Antminer S9 14 TH/s ?

So, which one is bigger GH/s or TH/s?
I am confused.

Comment: TH/s is bigger than GH/s, maybe this BAIKAL X10 mines another currency where 10GH/s makes more money than 14TH/s in bitcoin.

Comment: A quick google query tells me it mines dash.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is too localized and is unlikely to help future visitors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TH/s is bigger than GH/s. But there are many different kinds of hashes that you can do and some pay more than others. The Antiminer S9 does SHA256d hashes which tend to pay the least per hash of any hashing algoirthm because they are the simplest.

Answer (score 1):

GH/s stands for gigahash per second

TH/s stands for terahash per second

*Giga-* and *tera-* are SI prefixes just like *kilo-* and *mega-* and they are used everywhere (kilometer, megahertz, gigahertz, gigabyte, terabyte, ...). You can find the full list of SI prefixes here:

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix#List_of_SI_prefixes

So, to sum up:

```
1 kH/s = 1000^1 = 1 000 hashes per second
1 MH/s = 1000^2 = 1 000 000 hashes per second
1 GH/s = 1000^3 = 1 000 000 000 hashes per second
1 TH/s = 1000^4 = 1 000 000 000 000 hashes per second
1 PH/s = 1000^5 = 1 000 000 000 000 000 hashes per second
1 EH/s = 1000^6 = 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 hashes per second
```